# How to Create 'how to use' screen (like Go launcher) for the first launch of app (Android)

Tags: android, screen

I just want to add a screen help just like that one is in Go Launcher.  The screen just loads in first time the app started in phone and with low opacity guides user to how to use that application with arrows and texts that notice.

Comment: what you have to do for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a flag in your app prefernces.

When your app starts the first time, set the flag and save it in the preferences. On startup check this flag and you can decide to show or hide your screen.

Some nice tutorials:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html

Comment: tnx for help but in addition I don't know how to make a low opacity activity over the other activitis !!!

Comment: What about a new activity with a new screen? After your "introduction-page" you call your main activity.